# Devexpress GridControl Master-detail with Entity Framework: How to set

Tags: mvvm, entity-framework-6, master-detail, gridcontrol, devexpress-wpf

I am trying to show data from two related entities in Devexpress masted-detail grid control

```
public class ParentTable
    {
      public int ParentID { get; set; }
      public string ParentData1 { get; set; }
      public string ParentData2 { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<ChildTable> ChildDataCollection { get; set; }

    }

public class ChildTable
    {
      public int ChildID { get; set; }
      public int ParentID { get; set; }
      public string ChildData1 { get; set; }
      public string ChildData2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Describe relation using Fluen API:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<ParentTable>()
                .HasKey(e=> e.ParentID)
                .HasMany(e => e.ChildDataCollection)
                .WithRequired()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentID });
```

ParentList is data from ParentTable and ChildList is from ChildDataCollection

Xaml:

```
<dxg:GridControl
  AutoPopulateColumns="True"
  CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentParentItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParentList}">
    <dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
     <dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding ChildDataCollection}">
     </dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor>
    </dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
   </dxg:GridControl>
```

If I set DataControlDetailDescriptor Item Source is ChildDataCollection everything is ok, but what to do if I need to modify this collection (I am creating a list according to these data and want to bind it to DataControlDetailDescriptor ItemSource)

I need ChildList would be detail ItemSource and I am not lucky... emty rows :(
I need this new ChildDataList